# Terminal printando em amarelo

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, estou aprendendo javascript e no meu terminal, quando rodo algum código, alguns prints saem em amarelo. Alguém sabe o motivo ? Obrigado.

```
const peso1 = 1.0
const peso2 = Number('2.0')
const peso3 = 1.1
console.log(peso1, peso2)  
console.log(Number.isInteger(peso1))
console.log(Number.isInteger(peso2))
console.log(Number.isInteger(peso3))
const avaliacao1 = 9.871
const avaliacao2 = 6.871
const total = avaliacao1 * peso1 + avaliacao2 * peso2
const media = total/ (peso1+peso2)
console.log(media)
console.log (media.toFixed(2))
console.log(media.toString())
console.log(media.toString(2))
console.log(typeof media)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

As cores são para diferenciar strings de outros tipos (como booleanos e números). No CMD do seu print as strings aparecem em branco.

Nos navegadores também há diferenciação de cores. Nos prints abaixo, alterei a linha `const peso1 = 1.0` para `const peso1 = "1.0"` (`1.0` como string, só para ilustrar):

**Chrome**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Firefox**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No Edge não há distinção de tipos (e cores). Por isso ele agrupou os 3 valores `23.15`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria legal um link pra algo que confirme isso (ok, o teste já confirma, mas se der um link pra documentação oficial ou algo do tipo, sempre valoriza)

Comment: Sim @Bacco, seria ótimo mesmo. Estou fazendo uma pesquisa ampla pra ver se acho alguma boa referência para inserir na resposta (mas tá difícil de achar).